# topology of the normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

show that

(**1**)S={f$\epsilon$X:$\lvert\ \int_a^b f(t)\,dt\rvert$ $\ge$1} is closed in 
X=(C[a,b],$\lVert\ . \rVert_ \infty$)

(**2**)S={f$\epsilon$X:f(0)=0} is  closed in  X=(C[a,b],$\lVert\ . \rVert_\infty$)

here,($\lVert\ . \rVert_ \infty$)is the sup norm on C[a,b]

i am really confused in how to solve such questions.please give detailed solution.

i tried to see the closedness of this space by considering the induced metric in this case.now,in the first question ,the metric is d(f,g)=$\lVert\ f-g\rVert_\infty$.now ,i am confused on how to find the boundary points of metric in this case,which would be sufficient to claim closedness of given normed space

also,is this a proper method of approach for this question or not??

Comment: What is $X$? Which norm is $\|\cdot\|$ supposed to be in the first question?  Perhaps you are confused, but please tell us what your thoughts are on the question, or what you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, please [format your questions using MathJax in the future](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360).

Comment: You have used the (nearly) same non-descriptive title for three questions in a row. Please try to make  your titles more descriptive (otherwise you will also run out of possible titles in about 2 questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, if $\{f_n\}\subseteq S$ and $f_n\to f\in X$, it means that 
$\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$. Then, using that $[a,b]$ is bounded and each $f_n,f$ continuos, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to0$ for each $x\in[a,b]$. So, given $\epsilon>0$, we have $-(b-a)\epsilon<f_n(x)-f(x)<\epsilon(b-a)$ for $n$ enough large. Integrating both sides give us $\left|\int_a^bf_n(x)dx-\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|<\epsilon$ for $n$ enough large, and thus, $\left|\int_a^bf_n(x)dx-\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|\to 0$. It implies $\left|\int_a^bf_n(x)dx\right|\to\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|$. Now use definition of $S$

For the second one, if $\{f_n\}\subseteq S$ and $f_n\to f\in X$, it means that $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$. Then, using that $[a,b]$ is bounded and each $f_n,f$ continuos, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to0$ for each $x\in[a,b]$. In particular for $x=0$ the last is true. Now use definition of $S$

In general, convergence in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ intuitively means that the graph of each $f_n$ is looking more and more to graph of $f$